# Почему не грузится картинка в html коде?

Tags: javascript, html

В linux сделал сайт, в index.html впихнул код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Атрибуты тега img</title>
</head>
<body>
     <img src="file:///C:\Users\cu_1\Desktop\sublime\images\1.avif">

</body>
</html>
```

В браузере не открывает картинку. Сам файл находится в windows.
Пробовал переносить файл с картинкой в linux, в /home/user/ - тож самое.
Пробовал другой код с лампочкой- все работает, но изображения лампочки тож нет :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>

<p>JavaScript can change HTML attribute values.</p>

<p>In this case JavaScript changes the value of the src (source) attribute of an image.</p>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulbon.gif'">Turn on the light</button>

<img id="myImage" src="pic_bulboff.gif" style="width:100px">

<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulboff.gif'">Turn off the light</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: какие ошибки в консоли браузера?

Comment: 1. В линуксе нет ни "диска С" ни таких слешей в пути к файлам. 2 Учись пользоваться инструментами вебмастера в браузере.

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали на Хабре:
нужно переместить файл с картинкой в папку с index.html,
и прописать типа так  `<img src="./1.avif">`
Но вопрос со вторым кодом (лампочка) пока не решен

Comment: две точки означает выход из папки на один уровень, а одна точка таже папка, все дело в ваших путях. чтобы вам лучше решить эту задачу, лучше почитайте про пути https://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/izobrazheniya/dobavlenie-risunka, а то вам подсказали для конкретного фото...и вы переместили фото... Это на самом деле легко, если вникнуть. Удачи

Comment: вот документация на русском https://www.schoolsw3.com/html/html_filepaths.php

Comment: чтобы конкретно с лампочкой решить, вы кстати тоже самое можете сделать, переложить гифку лампочки в папку с index.html и прописать путь `<img src="./pic_bulbon.gif">` или off, я так понимаю там выкл/вкл

Comment: Спасибо! Про пути я понял. А вот как "переложить гифку лампочки в папку с index.html" чет не пойму. С фото понятно: скачал в windows и потом файл через winscp (например) перенес в linux в папку с index.html. А с кодом "лампочки" как быть?

Comment: Понял! Нашел в гугле по ссылке лампочку